# como hacer un select con datos json dentro de codigo html creado con .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, laravel-8

he intentado de todo, visto todos los videos y post del internet, no se si es posible tengo un array json que traigo de un controlador php, con este json tengo que hacer un select que pueda usar dentro de un codigo html que es creado dentro de la misma funcion con un innerHTML. todo esto para insertar una tabla generada por js dentro de mi vista.

este es un ejemplo del json que trae

```json
[{"id":1,"nameSfp":"Cantv"},{"id":2,"nameSfp":"b"},{"id":3,"nameSfp":"dsfasdf"}]
```

este es mi funcion js

dentro de el `for(i=0;i<cant_puertos;i++)`
esta el codigo html al que le quiero poner los option con el array json

```javascript
function admiuplink() {
    
    $("#formulario_registro").hide();
    //peticion ajax
    $.ajax({
        url:'/gpon/public/sfpNames',
        type:'GET',
        
        
    }).done(function(data){
        var sfp=JSON.stringify(data);
        document.write(sfp);
        //tabla de puertos uplink
        if (validar("puerto_uplin") == false){$("#puerto_uplin").focus();   return false;};
        var cant_puertos = document.getElementById("puerto_uplin").value;
        
        for( i = 0;i < cant_puertos;i++) 
        {
            document.getElementById("tablaprueba").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" id="puerto_'+i +'" name="puerto_'+i +'" value="'+i +'" required="required" placeholder="puerto" class="form-control tip" maxlength="9" title="Ingresa el número sin puntos"/></td><td> <input type="checkbox" checked id="estado_'+i +'" name="estado_'+i +'" required="required"  class="form-control tip" /></td><td> <select for="form_estado_id" id="sfp" name="sfp"  required="required" class="form-control">'+for(var item in sfp){$('#sfp').append('<option value='+  +'>'+ +'</option>');}+'</select></td></tr>';
        }
        /*$.each(sfp,function(id,name){
            select.append('<option value=' + name.id + '>' + name.name + '</option>');
        });*/
        
    });   
  
    $("#formulario_registro_2").show();
    
}
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que contienen codigo dentro de una imagen, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para simplificar las cosas, crea una función que se encargue de generar y devolver elementos `tr`. A esta función le pasarás el índice como parámetro:

```
function createTr (i) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    
    tr.innerHTML = `<tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="puerto_${i}" name="puerto_${i}" value="${i}" required="required" placeholder="puerto" class="form-control tip" maxlength="9" title="Ingresa el número sin puntos"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked id="estado_${i}" name="estado_${i}" required="required" class="form-control tip" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select for="form_estado_id" id="sfp_${i}" name="sfp" required="required" class="form-control"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>`
    
    return tr;
}
```

Por último, una vez la llamada ajax finalice y los datos en formato JSON hayan sido convertidos a un objeto, genera los `tr` y, a su vez, recorre el objeto convertido para crear los `option` y darles un valor. Por último, añade el nuevo `tr` a la tabla:

```
/*...*/
$.ajax({

    /*...*/
    
}).done(function (data) {

    const sfp = JSON.parse(data);
    
    /*...*/
    
    const cant_puertos = +document.querySelector('#puerto_uplin').value;
    const tabla = document.querySelector('#tablaprueba');
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < cant_puertos; i++) {
        const tr = createTr(i);
        
        for (const [, value] of Object.entries(sfp)) {
            tr.querySelector('select[name="sfp"]').innerHTML = `<option value="${value.id}">${value.nameSfp}</option>`;
        }
        
        tabla.appendChild(tr);
    }
    
});
```

Cuando llamamos a la función `createTr(index)` estamos creando un elemento `tr`, por lo que después podemos acceder a sus elementos hijos (en este caso el `select`). Organizando el código de esta manera se vuelve más sencillo y legible.

[Aquí tienes un codepen](https://codepen.io/heivask/pen/ZEyazpK) con un ejemplo funcional.

**A tener en cuenta:**

Los IDs deben ser únicos, hay que tener especial cuidado cuando se generan elementos dinámicamente con bucles.

`JSON.stringify()` convierte un objeto a string, `JSON.parse()` convierte un string a un objeto.

**Véase también:**

- [Document.querySelector() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Unary plus (+) - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)
- [Template literals (Template strings) - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [JSON - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#static_methods)
- [ES5 vs. ES6 Syntax. EcmaScript (ES) is a standardised… | by Wilsen Tjhung | CAMS Engineering](https://engineering.carsguide.com.au/es5-vs-es6-syntax-6c8350fa6998)

*Nota: aunque este sitio está en español, es importante leer las documentaciones en inglés, pues en otros idiomas pueden (y suelen) estar desactualizadas.*